# POST Method in route gives error 404 - Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to generate a random password on button click but it leads to Error 404

**The Form**

```
<form style="position: relative; left: -15px" action="{{ route("dashboard.users.generate-app-password-store") }}" method="POST">                       
   @csrf

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right mt-2">
        {{ trans("translation.generate-password") }}
    </button>
</form>
```

**The Controller Function**

```
public function generateAppEmailPasswordStore(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($request->uid);

    $user->app_email_password_store = Hash::make(Str::random(8));
    
    $user->app_email_password_store = $request->app_email_password_store;
    
    $user->save();  
    
    Alert::flash(trans('translation.email-account-created'));

    return redirect()->route('dashboard.users.profile', ['id' => $user->id]);
}
```

**The route** (prefix => dashboard is the main route group)

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'user', 'middleware' => 'checkRole:admin'], function () {
    Route::post('/generate-app-password-store', 'Dashboard\UsersController@generateAppEmailPasswordStore')->name('dashboard.users.generate-app-password-store');
});
```

**The error**
[image]

Comment: your prefix contain just the /user, where is the dashboard before the /user?

Comment: @Thamer is above the routes as main group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably recieving 404 because of this line in the controller method.

```
$user = User::findOrFail($request->uid)
```

Check if you get the correct value for `$request->uid` or if there is a user with the given ID.

Otherwise it will throw a 404 error.

Comment: Yep that was the problem, i had no uid so i make a jquery function to generate random passworn on click and i append that to the password value, then an update button to update the credentials.

Answer (score 0):

either change your dashboard.user.generate-app-password-store (instead of dashboard.users.generate-app-password-store) in your view

or

change your route prefix to users (instead of user)

Comment: Changed the `dashboard.users.generate-app-password-store` to `dashboard.user.generate-app-password-store` 

Error again

Comment: can you post output of your php artisan route:list

Comment: POST     | dashboard/user/generate-app-password-store  | dashboard.users.generate-app-password-store | App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard\UsersController@generateAppEmailPasswordStore |

Comment: now change the view to <form style="position:relative;left:-15px" action="{{ route('dashboard.users.generate-app-password-store') }}" method="post">                       
   @csrf
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right mt-2">
            {{ trans("translation.generate-password") }}
     </button>
</form

Comment: still the same ...

Comment: need more info. Please change your question code with full route file and also controller and view code. Otherwise it looks good with this amount of code.

Comment: may be this line is giving the 404 error when you redirect the page. check if that route exist in your route list.  ---> return redirect()->route("dashboard.users.profile", ["id" => $user->id]);

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you mismatch the " usage.

```
action="{{ route("dashboard.users.generate-app-password-store") }}"
```

should be

```
action="{{ route('dashboard.users.generate-app-password-store') }}"
```

The reasoning is that you close the action too early.

> action="{{ route("

Comment: the change of the action part made no difference